# Java Spring Project Architecture

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Java and Spring and am working on a project that will create yaml files and serve to the client via REST API. I have working code but I dont use @Bean, @Repository, or @Service annotations anywhere and I'm concerned my project is not utilizing Spring correctly.

Here is the flow:

1. User sends post request with params
2. Java code receives params, validates, and then selects what DB to connect to based on user input.
3. Connect to DB and get table metadata. No queries, only JDBC getColumns method.
4. Build yaml config files based on results from DB
5. Serve files back to client.

I feel like this doesn't follow the typical use case of Spring, but have no idea. How would you organize code/classes and make use of Spring annotations in this type of project?

Edit: not looking for exact code, only general project layout or maybe a pattern to follow.

Comment: For the future, this question is getting downvoted because it's too vague and asks for tutorial-esque walkthrough. However, because you've provided the detailed steps of your business logic, I decided to answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd organise the workflow you've presented as follows:

- Receive user's requested in `@Controller` annotated module. This is the layer you may want to use for input validation and input parsing. No business logic here.
- Pass input arguments to a `@Service` which would apply business conditions to that reach conclusion as to what data is requested and where to get it from.
- Each possible data source should be available as a `@Repository`. If the `@Service` has to decide which one to use, then they should all be defined as it's dependencies. In these modules should be hidden the code responsible for DB manipulation.
- Results fetched from a `@Repository` should be parsed into desired format by the `@Service`. If there's a business logic to be applied, it should be applied here.
- Formatted output should be returned to `@Controller` which encapsulates it accordingly to protocol (HTTP) standards and sends it back to the user.

Overall:

- `@Controller` interacts with the client / user
- `@Service` applies business logic
- `@Repository` interacts with DB or external data sources.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!